# onLocationChanged not called to retrieve position

Tags: android, google-maps

I' m developing an app that use the `google maps api`, now it worked fine into my real device which i used to the test the app.Few days ago i made an hard reset on my tablet and when i tried to test my app again, it didn't work as before.so in my logcat i see that the `locationClient` is connected, but it can't recognize my position, so `onLocationChanged` is never called.

i notice this into my logcat:

```
I/Google Maps Android API(2924): Google Play services client version: 5089000
I/Google Maps Android API(2924): Google Play services package version: 5089032
```

i know that these are two different versions of google play services, i can't understand how to fix it, because before tablet's hard reset,i hadn't got this info into logcat.

this is my manifest.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.logic.main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.logic.main.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.logic.main.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.logic.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logic.maps.activity.MapsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.logic.maps.backgroundService.LocationBackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MyApiKey" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener, OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener {

    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000;

    private GoogleMap map = null;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location myLocation;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LatLng newPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL).setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        if (locationClient != null)
            // connect the client to the Google Play services
            locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //THIS IS NEVER CALLED
        newPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        myLocation = location;
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPosition, 15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        //*************************** AT THE BEGINNING THIS IS CALLED***************/
        // BUT onLocationChanged is never called
        Toast.makeText(this, "I'm bringing you to your area.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    [...]
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Replace MyApiKey with your actual key.

Comment: I wrote MyApiKey, for privacy, but in my project there is a real api key.

Comment: Have you put any log in onLocation changed? Sure that its not returning you any location?

Comment: i ' m sure because i have inserted a log and a Toast inside onLocationChanged. I see that locationClient is connected, because onConnected is called, but onLocationChanged is never called.

Comment: In your phone : Go to your locations and security tab in settings and see if "google play services" has permission for your location.

Comment: i don't understand what you wrote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60818/discussion-between-amalbit-and-cimat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest Google Play Services from the Android SDK manager

Answer (score 1):

Enable location services:

settings->location and security->under my location-> select use wireless and use gps.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

// Getting the name of the best provider
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

// Getting Current Location
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000L, 1f, (LocationListener) this);
```