# Differences between google play services client and google play package version

Tags: android, google-play-services

i notice this into my logcat:

```
I/Google Maps Android API(2924): Google Play services client version: 5089000
I/Google Maps Android API(2924): Google Play services package version: 5089034
```

i know that these are two different versions of google play services.Can someone tell me the differences between these version?

Should their version be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Package version** :  Is what you add to your project.  (Google play service Lib)
**client version** : Is the actual version of the google play services installed in your phone.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have a question, these versions have to be the same?

Comment: I am not sure about that. But Its always a best practice to have the latest ones supported.

Comment: i have a problem in my application, i have installed the latest google play services for my app and the latest for my phone, but these versions still are different.

Comment: That will not cause you any problem. its not necessary to make them equal. I checked my project just now. Its working fine with different versons.

Comment: i cant understand why, my locationClient is connected, but `onLocationChanged` is never called, either at the beginning.

Comment: Make sure that, your app has permissions for fine and course location.

Comment: see this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704410/onlocationchanged-not-called-to-retrieve-position

Comment: Thats the best and simplest explanation. Thank you. One question though, because of this different versions, will there be any issues? Like I try to run geofence in my phone, but the intent service wont trigger. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Vishnu Its best to update the Google play service Lib in our app to the latest. If our package version is greater than client version, then we need to ask the user to update the phones google play service. If our client version is older, then its okay as google play service is backward compatible. Yes, many issues do arises because of this. But I am not aware of the one you just mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that you should always have the "latest" version supported. For example, if you do something like this in build.gradle

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

it will use the latest package version available. But sometimes, an update is released through the sdk to developers much before its counterpart client version hits the Play Store. @Cimat, I believe this reason behind the problem you had. Staying only as updated as the available client version ensures crashes don't happen, while providing you with the upgrades. Android automatically updates the Google Play Services jar anyways, so you need not worry about user laziness.

Answer (score 1):

@amalBit, you're wrong.

client version is what you've added to gradle dependencies.

Package version : Is the actual version of the google play services installed in your phone.

client version : Is what you add to your project. (Google play service Lib)